# how to drive 500W of leds

Tags: led

I am currently developing a project that needs 9 led stripes, each led stripe has 5 meters, 300 leds, it consumes 60W per stripe in a total of 540W...

This are the led stripes - 5M 12W/M 24V SMD 2835

This led stripes use a 24V power supply.

The thing is I want to drive them with an arduino and PWM. What would I need to do it. I was looking for something like CAT4101 but I never dealt with so much power before and I would like your advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The led strips will have their own current limiting / drivers. A couple of quick calculations:

- 24V at 12W is (I=P/V) 12/24 = 0.5A per meter
- 5 meters = 0.5*5 = 2.5A

So each strip takes 2.5A. The CAT4101 is a 1A max driver, but since it is a *constant current* driver it's not suitable for a strip that has its own current control built in.

I suspect each meter consists of 10 chains of 6 LEDs with a current limiting resistor or two. Out of interest, calculations:

- 6 LEDs at (say) 3V forward voltage would be 18V.
- 24 - 18 = 6 volts to drop
- 500mA divided by 10 chains = 50mA
- R=V/I = 6 / 0.05 = 120Ω current limiting resistors.
- P=I²R = 0.05²×6 = 300mW dissipated from the resistors.

Instead all you need is an N-channel MOSFET as a low-side switch that can operate with that much current and not dissipate too much heat while switching. The more you derate the MOSFET the less heatsinking it would need.

A quick look on Digikey gave a possible match of [PSMN022-30PL](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/PSMN022-30PL,127/1727-5893-ND/2606361) - 30V, 30A, 27mΩ (typ) at 4.5V gate voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKQHep.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And I would need one of those for each led stripe? What if I get a 600W power supply? I don't think that the leds have drivers at all? I was thinking on direct power supply connection.... I guess that would be mistake right?

Comment: Ideally, yes - spread the load nicely. However one, with proper heat sinking, should be able to do all of them together (22.5A) at a pinch.

Comment: sorry I edited the question: What if I get a 600W power supply? I don't think that the leds have drivers at all? I was thinking on direct power supply connection.... I guess that would be mistake right?

Comment: Do you have a link to the LED strips?

Comment: it's in portuguese, but google translate should handle it:

Comment: https://goo.gl/qXX2IQ

Comment: Yes, it has current limiting resistors. You can see them between every three LEDs. They have most likely split the resistance across a couple of resistors to spread the dissipation, so they can use smaller resistors. So direct supply connection and a MOSFET to switch them is fine.

Comment: And yes, as I thought - you can tell by the cut points (where the metal pads are) that they are parallel chains of 6 LEDs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58816/discussion-between-killercode-and-majenko).